# Parsing JSON file with Jackson for Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Title says all. Trying to simply parse a JSON file I added to this android project via Jackson to use throughout my app.

I was able to to do this successfully in a regular Java Application, but not in an Android project for an unknown reason. Will post both codes.

Android Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream is = MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream("contacts.json");

        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        List<Contact> contacts = null;
        Contact contact = null;

        try {           
            // THIS IS THE LINE THAT BREAKS
            contacts = mapper.readValue(is, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Contact.class));
            contact = contacts.get(0);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }     
    }
}
```

Again, here's the line that breaks:

```
contacts = mapper.readValue(is, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Contact.class));
```

This is the LogCat of the error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
```

I've searched this plenty and have not found a solution for this trivial task. I'd like to also know why this code works in a Java Application but not in an Android Project. If onCreate could throw those exceptions like Main can in the Java App I think it would work, but obviously it can't.  Thanks for the solution in advance.

---

Just for reference, here is my working Java Application code of using Jackson to parse a JSON file.

```
package test;

// file with accessors and mutators for JSON
import test.Contact;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InputStream is = test.class.getResourceAsStream("contacts.json");
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        List<Contact> contacts = mapper.readValue(is, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, Contact.class));

        // point to first contact
        Contact contact = contacts.get(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
            contact = contacts.get(i);
            System.out.println(contact.getName());
            System.out.println(contact.getEmployeeId());
            System.out.println(contact.getCompany());
            System.out.println(contact.getDetailsURL());
            System.out.println(contact.getSmallImageURL());
            System.out.println(contact.getBirthdate());
            System.out.println(contact.getPhone().getWork());
            System.out.println(contact.getPhone().getHome());
            System.out.println(contact.getPhone().getMobile());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems that maybe the file can't be found from android's perspective, or whatever you are using to move the JSON file over isn't moving the whole the whole JSON file.

Comment: Wow, yes. It's always something like this. Problem was I had my JSON file in the assets folder which InputStream was not reading it from.

Comment: @LeliahJane Good, glad to hear you got the problem resolved! :)